# method created array to saved array

Tags: java, arrays

Im making a game thingamajig, which uses a large array (int[][]) as a map. I need to be able to take in different maps, and i have the code that goes map from a file -> array, but this is a method. is there a neat way to save this array and be able to access the data quickly without having to run the file-> array method every time?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a Java object to disk, it must implement the `Serializable` interface so one suggestion would be to wrap your `int[][]` array in a classe like

```
public class MyMap implelemts Serializable {
    private int[][] values;
    // getters, setters, constructor...
}
```

You can then use a `FileOutputStream` wrapped in an `ObjectOutputStream` to save the object to disk:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/path/to/file.ser"));
oos.writeObject(myMap);
oos.close();
```

Where `myMap` is an instance of the class that wraps your int array.

Retrieval in this case requires an instance of the whole object though so for your use case you might be better off with either a simple map file or with some kind of database on the backend.